# Outputting integers in a nested list to string in a text file

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, nested

So I currently have this code at the end of my program that allows the user to save the text file. I have no idea how to convert the data to string and that is what is giving me the error if i try to use this code.

```
save = input("Would you like to save the latest generation? ('y' to save):")
if save == 'y':
    destination = input("enter destination file name:")
    with open(destination, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in original_graph)
else:
    print("End of program.")
```

However, my `original_graph` is a nested list with only integer values, ex: `[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]`

How would I make it so that the text file is looks something like

`0110
0001
0010`

in the text file after I save it? Also, is there a way to prompt the user if they were overwrite an existing file?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mind having newlines between your values?

Comment: Newlines might be troublesome if I have to reuse the text file again for another program. I don't exactly know how to exclude things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compact way to write this is using list comprehensions. For convenience, I'll use `stdout` as the output file.

```
import sys

original_graph = [
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
]

f = sys.stdout
rows = [''.join([str(u) for u in row]) for row in original_graph]
f.write('\n'.join(rows) + '\n')
```

**output**

```
0110
0001
0010
```

To save the data to a file whose name is a string stored in `destination`, just do:

```
rows = [''.join([str(u) for u in row]) for row in original_graph]
with open(destination, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(rows) + '\n')
```

---

To check if a file already exists, use the [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) function. If you need further help on this aspect please ask a new question. Stack Overflow questions should contain a single question in order to maximize their usefulness for future readers.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without importing sys? I'm not really sure how it works. And thank you for the advice, I will remember not to ask multiple questions next time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to see if I can fully understand what happens in the line of code. I'm a little haze on what '\n' represents.

Comment: @George `\n` is the [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) for the newline character. Similarly, `\t` is the tab character. So `'\n'.join(rows)` says to join all the strings in `rows` into one big string, with a `\n` between each one. Then we add another `\n` at the end so that the file ends with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this works

```
original_graph=[[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
save = input("Would you like to save the latest generation? ('y' to save):")
if save == 'y':
    destination = input("enter destination file name:")
    with open(destination, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines('\t'.join(str(i) for i in original_graph))
else:
    print("End of program.")
```

Comment: This works but it prints out the nested list on one line on the text document. What if I wanted something like the example I put in the question on the text file? It wouldn't be a nested list but just rows of numbers.